# Group by month, type and category SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count

How can I create a SQL Server query using group by month, name and quantity? Is it possible to group by field and column values? In the example below I need to group cats and dogs in the Animal Category too, but the others one can be like the example.

Table:

[image: table]

My result:

[image: result]

What I did:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(CHAR(8), Date, 112) AS 'Date', 
    Product.Type AS 'Type',
    COUNT(DISTINCT Product.Id) AS 'Count',
    Product.Operation AS 'Operation'
FROM 
    Product 
GROUP BY 
    Product.Type, Product.Operation, CONVERT(CHAR(8), Product.Date, 112) 
ORDER BY 
    Product.Type
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate a bit more about the 'Name' field as well as the quantity filed.

Assumptions: The name field => type and quantity => count

The a possible solution is:

```
SELECT Month([Date]), [Name]=type, Quantity=count(*)
FROM Product
GROUP BY Month([Date]), type
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT 
  convert(char(8), [Date], 112) as 'Date'
  , case when P.[Type] in ('Cat', 'Dog') then 'Animal' else P.[Type] end AS 'Type'
  , COUNT(DISTINCT P.Id) AS 'Count'
  , P.Operation AS 'Operation'
FROM dbo.Product P
GROUP BY case when P.[Type] in ('Cat', 'Dog') then 'Animal' else P.[Type] end, P.Operation, Convert(char(8), [P.Date], 112) 
ORDER BY case when P.[Type] in ('Cat', 'Dog') then 'Animal' else P.[Type] end
```